# how to check the last run activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Suppose I have 5 activities , A, B, C, D, E.
C is the middle activity which decides if the activity that invoked C is A , then C should take the user to D , and if the activity that invoked C is B , then C should take the user to E. So is there any way to determine which of the activities were last run(A or B) so I can take the user to the corresponding activity after C(D or E)?

It is a bit complicated ,but this is the best way I can explain this.

Comment: Put the caller activity's name (or even easier, the target activity's name) in the intent for C. Then read it in C, and create the new intent based on that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at A and B use this

A:

```
Intent intnt = new Intent(this, C.class);
intnt.putExtra("source","A");
startActivity(intnt);
```

B:

```
Intent intnt = new Intent(this, C.class);
intnt.putExtra("source","B");
startActivity(intnt);
```

at C, `onCreate()`

```
String src = getIntent().getStringExtra("source");
if(src.equlas("A")){
//start D
}else if(src.equlas("B")){
//start E
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work , it force closes everytime :/

Comment: what do u mean? why do u need onPause()? best place for this is at onClick() for the button that starts the next activity...

Comment: and check the log to see whats wrong, we gave u they key, u need to put some effort in this!

Comment: It was giving me NullPointerException , everything was fine , i restarted the AVD , now its running fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

        A Activity code
        Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
        intent.putExtra("fromActivity","A");
        startActivity(intent);

        B Activity code
        Intent intent = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
        intent.putExtra("fromActivity","B");
        startActivity(intent);

        C Activity code
        if(getIntent().getStringExtra("fromActivity").equals("A")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(C.this,D.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(C.this,E.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Intent extras.

In A & B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class); // Or however you do it now 
intent.putExtra("caller", getClass()); // getClass must be called on the activity class here
// Do any stuff you want here to the Intent 
startActivity(intent); // Or however you do it now
```

In `onCreate` of C:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Class caller = (Class) intent.getSerializableExtra("caller");
if(caller == A.class) // A called C
```

And so on. Or even better, use the target classes.

In A & B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, C.class); // Or however you do it now 
intent.putExtra("target", D.class); // What should be called from C is put here 
// Do any stuff to the Intent you want here 
startActivity(intent); // Or however you do it now
```

In `onCreate` of C:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Class target = (Class) intent.getSerializableExtra("target"); // Put this class somewhere
```

And now to create the Intent for D/E:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, target);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always send information with intent using bundle while calling activity and read that information in called activity.In your case, you can do it like this:

from activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
i.putExtra("LAUNCHER", "A");
startActivity(i);
```

from activity B:

```
Intent i = new Intent(A.this,C.class);
i.putExtra("LAUNCHER", "B");
startActivity(i);
```

and Inside oncreate() of C, read it like this:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String code = extras.getString("LAUNCHER");

if(code == "A"){

Intent i = new Intent(C.this,D.class);
startActivity(i);
}else{
Intent i = new Intent(C.this,E.class);
startActivity(i);
}
```